# how to validate the array of Strings or integers ignoring the order in Karate?

Tags: testing, karate

$.entityDocTypes | not equal | array match failed at index 0 (LIST:LIST)
["Passport #","PRN"]
["PRN","Passport #"]

```
  $.entityDocTypes[0] | not equal (STRING:STRING)
  'Passport #'
  'PRN'
```

I am getting below assertion failure due to mismatch in the order of the elements in the array.

Comment: also read the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#json-arrays